# bootstrap multiple data-toggle on delete button?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, button, bootstrap-confirmation

I have a bootstrap delete button, to get popover on it I'm using bootstrap-confirmation.js. and now trying to use a tooltip on it but tooltip not working because of confirmation js. please anyone have a solution for this?

**This is my button**

```
 <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm mr-2" data-toggle="confirmation" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip">
     <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
 </button>
```

**This is my javascript**

```
$(function() {

  $('[data-toggle=confirmation]').confirmation({
       rootSelector: '[data-toggle=confirmation]',
       popout: true,
       btnOkClass: 'btn-success',
    });

  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to fix this, I wrapped my button icon with span and I gave tooltip for that span.

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm mr-2" data-toggle="confirmation" data-placement="top">
    <span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete series">
         <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
    </span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also change the selector to something else:

`$('[data-tooltip="tooltip"]').tooltip();`

And then just change it in the element `data-tooltip="tooltip"`

Comment: yes, but it has the same attributes that confirmation js also has like title, data-placement. it is conflicting